# Unable to develop assosciations between models in sequelize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I am creating realtionship (one to many) between User model and Task model
I have crated the reference column in the migration too
I am using sequlize ORM with sequelize cli. Everything works fine when I try alternative method that i will explain later but If i try to do it according the documentation it gives me error

Task is not associated to User

**WORKING ALTERNATIVE METHOD**

IN end of index.js file I created relations and it works as expected

```
db.user = require("../models/user.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.tasks = require("../models/Task.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.user.hasMany(db.tasks, { as: "user_tasks",foreignKey: "userId" });
db.tasks.belongsTo(db.user, {
  foreignKey: "userId",
  as: "task_user",
});
```

but when i follow the documetation i got error that i mentioned earlier

**According to document**

**Model** User.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User =sequelize.define('User',{
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
   },
   name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
   },
   age: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   },
   email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
   },
   createdAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE
  },
  updatedAt: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: DataTypes.DATE
  }
```

});

User.associate = (models) =>{

```
User.hasMany(models.Tasks, {
  as: 'user_tasks',
  foreignKey: 'userId'}
);
```

};

return User;
};

**Model:** Task.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const Task = sequelize.define('Task', {

    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
   },
   title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
   },
   userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
   },
    });


    Task.associate = function(models) {
      Task.belongsTo(models.User, { 
        as:'owner',
        foreignKey:'userId',
         onDelete: "cascade"
        });
    };
  
    return Task;
}
```

This is how i am trying to get data from database
**controller**

```
const User = db.user 
const {Tasks} = db.tasks

exports.usertasks = async(req,res)=>{

// const users =  await User(db.sequelize,db.Sequelize).findAll({
const users =  await User.findAll({
    
    include:[{model:Tasks,as:"user_tasks"}]
});
res.json(users)
console.log("All users with their associated tasks:", JSON.stringify(users, null, 4));
```

}

**My Index.js file**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname+'../models/', file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
console.log(model);

    
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
                                                    //relations THIS IS WORKING AND I AM JUST CURIOUS WHETHER TO USE THIS APPROACH OR NOT


// db.user = require("../models/user.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
// db.tasks = require("../models/Task.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

// db.user.hasMany(db.tasks, { as: "user_tasks",foreignKey: "userId" });
// db.tasks.belongsTo(db.user, {
//   foreignKey: "userId",
//   as: "task_user",
// });
module.exports = db;
```

I am also attaching the picture of successful response that I get with the alternative method.

[image]
*Kindly, guide whether the alternative method that I used is acceptable or should I stick to the documenation one?*

Answer (score 0):

`.associate` is not a native Model's method, so you need to call it manually.
I think in your `index.js` you want to do something like:

```js
'use strict';

const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const config = require('../config/config.json')[process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'];
const requireAll = require('require-all');

const sequelize = config.use_env_variable
  ? new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config)
  : new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

const db = { sequelize };

const modelsInitializers = Object.values(requireAll({
  dirname: __dirname,
  recursive: false,
  filter: (name) => name !== 'index.js' && name,
}));

const models = modelsInitializers.map((initializer) => {
  const model = initializer(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
  db[model.name] = model;
  return model;
});

models.forEach((model) => {
  if (model.associate) model.associate(db);
})

models.forEach((model) => {
  if (model.associate) model.associate(models);
  db[model.name] = model;
})


Object.entries().forEach(([modelName, model]) => {
  model.associate(models);
  db[modelName] = model;
});

module.exports = db;
```

Comment: It's already present in the index.js file as i mentioned i am using sequlize-cli so when i ran init command it generated models with index.php in it with other requried folders too

Comment: Could you update your question and add your current `index.js` there?

Comment: Sorry, i should've done it earlier. I have edited my question

Comment: I've updated my answer. Sorry if it doesnt suite your case. Good luck!

Comment: kindly, explain it a little